# How to add Navigation below tabbed content using jQuery UI Tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, navigation, jquery-tabs

I am using jQuery UI Tabs for a tabbed interface with panes that is using the default functionality. I would like to add additional navigation that appears outside of the .ui-tabs DIV that are just buttons contained inside an unordered list (in addition to the tabbed links at the very top).

Can someone tell me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [`select`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select) method in the tabs API.

1. Add an unordered list of buttons. I'm using the `data` attribute to associate a button with a tab:

   ```
   <ul>
       <li><button type="button" class="tabs-link" data-tab="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</button></li>
       <li><button type="button" class="tabs-link" data-tab="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</button></li>
       <li><button type="button" class="tabs-link" data-tab="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</button></li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. Bind a `click` event handler to those buttons:

   ```
   $("button.tabs-link").bind("click", function($event) {
       $event.preventDefault();
       $("#tabs").tabs("select", $(this).data("tab"));
   });
   ```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZnYC/